# How can I use Helvetica Light or Neue in moderncv?

Tags: fonts, moderncv

I have gotten Helvetica working in Xavier Danaux's moderncv by placing in the following lines in banking.sty to typeset my cv.tex file. I'm using texShop on OSX.

```
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I even tried

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}
```

to access my system fonts (Helvetica, Hel Neue and Hel Light are installed in my OS X) however I get he following error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I checked my fc-list in terminal and Helvetica Light and Neue are there. Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Are you compiling with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (minimum working example) that generates the warning message you mention. Are you running MacTeX2013 or an older vintage of MacTeX?

Comment: The first example should be compiled with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX; the second with XeLaTeX. In the first case, load `fontenc` before the font package. To use Neue or Light I think you need to go with your second solution and use XeLaTeX. But then you need to make sure that you are getting the name of the font correct. You can use OS X's font management application to get this name (FontBook?).

Comment: @cfr: Instead of XeLaTeX LuaLaTeX would also be possible.

Comment: Why do you put those first three lines in `banking.sty`? Put them in your preamble itself. It works. (I mean the lines starting from `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}...`)